# Fetch all resources which send data to a particular log analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-log-analytics

Is there a way to see all resources sending logs to a log analytics workspace using powershell? I am able to find a method names `Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsDataSource` but it accepts `Name` as a parameter which is mandatory while I want to fetch all resources irrespective of name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the source is not a resource itself, its where you want to get the data from. so you can find all the resources

```
$dataSources = Get-AzOperationalInsightsDataSource -Workspace $workspace -Kind AzureActivityLog
```